# Fabric JS: Set Image positioning with coordinates (x,y)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

After the copping image I don't save the cropped image but I get the data in which X,Y,Width,height are there. I am using full image in the fabric canvas and then I need to set position the image by those data in fabric canvas.

In Short: I need to set coordinates (x,y) of the image of the canvas. Not the canvas. Only to the image of the canvas.
I tried setOriginX,setOriginY but doesn't showing result as per the need. It gets the 0,0 position.
Here is the code

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var imgElement = document.getElementById('myimg');
var CanImg = new fabric.Image(imgElement, {
    setScaleX: img_data.x,
    setScaleY: img_data.y
});
$('#canvas').attr('width',img_data.width);
$('#canvas').attr('height',img_data.height);
canvas.setHeight(img_data.height);
canvas.setWidth(img_data.width);
CanImg.selectable = false;
canvas.add(CanImg);
```

What would be the best to do this?

Comment: can you please provide some code or reference link or some images what you want?

Comment: Edited question with the code in which the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer "Canvas background and overlay" in [this](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-4/) link. They have explained  ways how to set image as canvas background. Now as you said that you have cropped image data, than you can just crop your image first and than you can set the image as per given link

Comment: Cropping image is fine. I have done the task. I just want to use similar like this
context.drawImage(img,sx,sy,swidth,sheight,x,y,width,height);
I want to use sx,sy in fabric js for the image.